# Child View Not Appearing Under ViewPager in LinearLayout

Tags: android

I want to put a Button under my ViewPager that is in a LinearLayout.

I've tried using different gravities, 0dp on the LinearLayout, but the ViewPager always shoves the button out of the view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/crime_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="foo"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

I expected a Button to be under the ViewPager.

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="16dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn_foo"
    android:id="@+id/crime_view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_foo"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="foo" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: was helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `layout_heigh` of the `ViewPager` to 0dp and the button's height to `wrap_content` like below...

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/crime_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="foo"/>
```

This is really trivial stuff and I would strongly recommend you to read a tutorial about it to understand why

Comment: Thank you. If you know of any good tutorials, they would be greatly appreciated. I am reading Big Nerd Ranch Android ATM at about 33%.